# What does "$" mean in CSS?

Tags: css

I see the "$" a lot in CSS.

Here's the example:

```
$bg-color: #F1E9DA;
$link-text-color: #fff;
$button-bg-1: #541388;
$button-bg-2: #D90368;
$button-bg-3: #104547;
$button-bg-4: #4F000B;
$button-bg-5: #F28123;
$border-radius: 6px;
$overlay-color: #fff;
```

What does this do?

Comment: I suggest that you perform more research into this matter using criteria such as `css symbols`, etc.  Also, if you have any examples of where `$` has been used in the above manner, then please include some of them.

Answer (score 2):

This is not css. It's SASS, SCSS or other preprocessor. Preprocessor of CSS. http://sass-lang.com/

Basically, it is a variable. So you can call it in other property.

For example. (SCSS)

```
$c: center;

.aligncenter {
  text-align: $c;
}
```

SASS

```
$c: center

.aligncenter
  text-align: $c
```

Answer (score 2):

As the above answer says it is SASS/SCSS variable which can be used anywhere in that file. This gets converted to CSS using GULP where the $variables are replaced with the CSS values in the original CSS file.